# What happened to Web.Authenticate.Facebook?

Tags: facebook, haskell

In previous versions of the [authenticate package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/authenticate/0.11.1/doc/html/Web-Authenticate-Facebook.html), there was something for Facebook authentication. Why does it not exist in the [newer versions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/authenticate)? Does it have to do with the fact that the Facebook API changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code was superseded by the more comprehensive [fb package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fb). It was a mistake on my part to not mention this in the package description itself (you're not the first to get caught by this change). I've updated the cabal file and uploaded a [new version to Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/authenticate). Hopefully that will avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/yesodweb/authenticate/commit/22f331b726ac142bde3765d98aa3c539f148ae39). As for why, you'd have to ask Michael Snoyman himself; there's no issue corresponding to commit that I could find. I suspect the code had simply become outdated because of Facebook updates.

However, since [Facebook support OAuth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (and indeed this seems to be what the old code was based on), you may be able to use [authenticate-oath](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/authenticate-oauth), which contains the OAuth code that was split out from authenticate proper. (If this does work, then that may be why the Facebook-specific support was removed: it would be redundant to the generic OAuth code.)